# Selenium Remote Webdriver IE9 Window minimized to task bar

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-9, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium Remote web driver to test my application in IE9 and the test is running fine in the remote machine. The only problem I am facing is, the IE 9 browser is minimized in the task bar as it opens. I need it to open so that I can see it by default. The capabilities currently set is as follows.

```
capabilities.setVersion("9");
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
```

The code to maximize the window `driver.manage().window().maximize()` works fine as I can see the window maximized when I click on the IE icon in the system tray.

What am I missing to open the window?

Thanks in Advance,

DeeJay

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to that PC with admin's rights:

Open window's registry, look for this key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

And delete the key: Window_Placement

Then restart

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it, but the result is same. Also the deleted entry is added once the test is completed.